# Why did the push_back method stop working at the second stage of the loop?

Tags: c++

You need to enter the elements of a two-dimensional vector. Here is the code:

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int n, m;
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> vect = {{}};
    cout << "Enter n and m" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    int a[m];
    cout << "Enter vector elements" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cin >> a[j];
            cout << a[j] << endl;
            vect[i].push_back(a[j]);
            cout << vect[i][j] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    };
return 0;
};
```

`.

At each step of the second stage of the cycle, I check if everything worked out. The stages of the second cycle are separated by an additional empty line, just in case. The first step of the loop, which enters all the elements of the first row of the vector, works fine. The second stage allows you to enter a[j] only once and print it to the terminal. The string vect[i].push_back(a[j]); is no longer fulfilled. The program terminates at this point (the IDE does not report errors). Why?

Comment: Note "int a[m];" is not valid (standard) C++, use a std::vector for that too. And you I think you forgot to push_back a new vector for each loop of i.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of that raw array anyways. It's not necessary, a local `int` variable for receiving the input should suffice.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually no `int` variable is required for receiving the input. We can read input directly to `vect[i][j]` after allocating elements.

Comment: @MikeCAT sure, but the question asks for `push_back()` specifically

Comment: The reason is that `vect` has only one element, and the `vect[i].push_back(a[j])`  - when `i` is non-zero - attempts to call `push_back()` for non-existent `vect[i]` - so behaviour is undefined.    You need to resize `vect` itself BEFORE accessing `vect[i]`.   A `vector`s `operator[]()` does not magically resize the vector if you attempt to access non-existent elements.

Comment: Reploace `[]` with `.at()` and you will get a nice exception telling you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The vector

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> vect = {{}};
```

has only one element, so accessing `vect[1]`, `vect[2]`, etc. is illegal.
You have to allocate enough elements.

Also note that VLA (Variable-Length Array) like `int a[m];` is not in the C++ standard, so you should ust `std::vector` also for `a`.

In conclusion, instead of this:

```cpp
    vector<vector<int>> vect = {{}};
    cout << "Enter n and m" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    int a[m];
```

You should use this:

```cpp
    cout << "Enter n and m" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    vector<vector<int>> vect(n);
    vector<int> a(m);
```

Or this:

```cpp
    vector<vector<int>> vect;
    cout << "Enter n and m" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    vect.resize(n);
    vector<int> a(m);
```

Comment: There doesn't even seem to be a need for `a` to be an array or vector, since it's only used for reading one input at a time

Comment: @UnholySheep Then `a` is completely not required and input can be read directly to `vect[i][j]` after allocating elements.